Algebraic Data Types で自前のListを作るときは、 空 と :: だけを作るのでしょうか？
Algebraic Data Types を備えた言語で自前のListを作る例として、下記を見ました。
名前つきパラメータとGADT｜プログラング言語Idrisに入門させたい（v0.9）

data List a = Nil | (::) a (List a)


YouTube: Nathan Holland- GADTs and You; Writing Safer Code Using GADTs- λC 2019 5分22秒あたり

type 'a list = 
  | []
  | (::) of 'a * 'a list

let empty : 'a list = []
let fibs : int list = [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13;]


どちらも、空のときと、連結のときを data もしくは type で作っています。
Algebraic Data Types を備えた言語に馴染みがないのですが、これはもうそういうものなのでしょうか？
これらの言語に馴染みがないので、質問自体が変かもしれないですが、

dataやtypeの中に記載するのはこれで十分（多すぎず・少なすぎない）であるとなぜわかりますか？

:: は、dataやtypeの中に書かないといけないのでしょうか？たとえば別途中間演算子 _::_ として作って（作れるのかどうかはこれらの言語に詳しくないので不明ですが）しまってもよいのではないかと思っています。
dataやtypeは最終的に自前のListを返せばよいので、たとえば、最初から1,2,3つ目の要素をListとして返すといったような関数はdataやtypeの中には書けないのでしょうか？仮に書けたとした場合は、書かないものなのでしょうか？（強引ですがオブジェクト指向的にみると(?)、dataやtypeの中にあったほうが、処理がまとまっていてよいようにも思います。::連結はdataやtypeの中に書いたので他の連結に似たような処理も中に書いてよいのでは?）
たとえば他にも、Swiftでは、ある型からある型に変換する際は、コンバーターを設けるのではなくて、コンバーターに相当するイニシャライザー（Javaでいうコンストラクタ）を変換元の方に生やして変換しようという流派もあります。そういった考えを使うと、文字列からListに変換するような処理も dataやtypeに書いてもよいのでは？（上記言語で書けるのかどうかはわかってませんが、IdrisならGADTなのでできそう?）などが思い浮かびます




代数的データ型 (Algebraic Data Types, ADT) に初めて触れて、かつ他のプログラミング言語との類推から違和感を覚えているので、代数的データ型の役割を理解したいという質問だと受け取りました。自分なりに説明してみます。
構文について
まず自前のリスト型を定義する例ですが、最初は :: を使わずに Cons という名前で構成子（コンストラクタ）を作って実装してみるのが分かりやすいです。たとえば OCaml 風に書くと以下のように 'a mylist 型を定義できます。
type 'a mylist = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist

このように定義すると、たとえば int mylist 型の値は以下のように定義できます。
let lst = Cons (1, Cons (2, Cons (3, Nil)))

データとしてはこれで充分で、int * int mylist 型の値を格納している Cons と、何も格納していない Nil の連続になっている形です。ここで、int mylist は型であり、Cons は構成子として値を作っているという区別に注意してください。（更に OCaml に限った話をすると、構成子は関数とも異なります。）
組み込み型の方の list では Cons に代わる構成子として :: という名前を採用しており、これが特別に中置記法で使えて 1 :: (2 :: (3 :: [])) と書け、更にこれが糖衣構文で [1; 2; 3] と書ける……という風になっています。
リストを表す型以外の例として、たとえば二分木を表す型を定義しようとしたらどうなるかを考えて実装してみると、より理解が深まるでしょう。
データ型とメソッドについて
次にメソッドとの紐付けについてです。ここでいう 'a mylist 型はあくまでデータがどのような構造をしているのかを表しているのみであり、メソッドとは紐付いていません。代数的データ型というのはあくまで型についての用語です。メソッドと紐付けたいのであればそれは別の言語機能になります。
別の言語機能として型とメソッドをひとまとめに考える方法はいくつか考えられます。たとえば OCaml ではモジュールという、いくつかの型やメソッドなどを名前空間の下に入れられる機能があります: https://ocaml.org/docs/modules。他にも Rust の trait のように型に紐付いたメソッドを定義できるようにするやり方もあります: https://doc.rust-jp.rs/book-ja/ch10-02-traits.html。
このあたり文脈やプログラミング言語によって多少用語が異なり混乱を生むことがあるので、それぞれの言語のドキュメントを参照なさるのが近道かなと思います。
